# Cannot implicitly convert type delegate to string

Tags: c#, string, delegates, implicit-conversion

I'm trying to create a class that at runtime can be pointed to various data inputs.  To do this I am trying to use delegates.  I have a worker method that returns a string (in the actual implementation, there would be others to choose from).  The return value of the  delegate is then returned from a method exposed to the rest of the code.

```
private delegate string delMethod();
private static delMethod pntr_Method = new delMethod(OneDelegateMethod);

public static string ExposedMethod()
{
    return pntr_Method;
}
public static string OneDelegateMethod()
{
    return "This is a string";
}
```

I'm getting this error

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'OB.DataBase.delMethod' to 'string'

I'm puzzled why I get this, when this method has worked for bools and `IDataReaders`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to call the delegate and return the value, you have to use "()":

```
public static string ExposedMethod()
{
    return pntr_Method();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the obvious to me.  I think I need to quit for the day.

Answer (score 1):

You need to call the delegate in order for it to return a string value. Delegates are really just pointers to methods, and need to be called using parenthesis in order to execute the method they point to.
Here is a fixed version of your code:

```
private delegate string delMethod();
private static delMethod pntr_Method = new delMethod(OneDelegateMethod);

public static string ExposedMethod()
{
    return pntr_Method();
}
public static string OneDelegateMethod()
{
    return "This is a string";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to invoke the target method:

```
public static string ExposedMethod()
{
  return pntr_Method();
}
```